# PHP Script for contact form to email

Tags: php, email

I am using the below PHP script in my contact form to send enquiries to my email address. I tested it using XAMP but no email came through. Is that due to it being tested on a local host or is there something up with my code?
Please have a look below and let me know, as you can tell I am very new to PHP.

thanks,

Joe.

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "angliojoe@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "eMail enquiry";


     function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.         ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you   submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
          if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
           $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
         if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
          $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
           if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
           died($error_message);
  }
           $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

        function clean_string($string) {
          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }

        $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
     'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    ?>

    <!-- include your own success html here -->

     Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you shortly.

     <?php
     }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's probably because you don't have a mail server installed on your local machine.

You might want to try uploading it to a Linux web server (I assume you're using Windows) that also has an email server installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PHPMailer, but then you need an smtp server. [PHPMailer at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

Comment: That won't help. PHPMailer relies on the `mail()` function. Which is what is not working.

Comment: @EM-Creations No that's incorrect "Sends email via sendmail, PHP mail(), QMail, **or with SMTP**."

Comment: That depends on how you set up the PHPMailer, take a look at their documentation. Regardless he's not likely to have either IMAP or SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

remove the @ symbol before mail() and check with apache error log for actual mailer problem.

**Note:** The problem should be in mailer configuration. you must be defined smtp details in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

check phpinfo(); if there is any entry for smtp? sendmail? if you have smtp server installed then call mail('you@yourmail.com','subject','bodyMessage') and see if you get any mail?